# Catch a lot of errors on node.js (npm)

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I am attaching the result npm audit.
Attempts to solve the problem on their own have led nowhere. I would be grateful if someone could explain the essence of the problem. Can't fix it for a long time. Maybe perhaps the solution is simple and logical, but unfortunately it is not obvious to me.

```
       High            Regular expression denial of service                          

       Package         glob-parent                                                   

       Patched in      >=5.1.2                                                       

       Dependency of   gulp [dev]                                                    

       Path            gulp > glob-watcher > chokidar > glob-parent                  

       ------------------------------------------------------------

       High            Prototype Pollution in set-value                              

       Package         set-value                                                     

       Patched in      >=4.0.1                                                       

       Dependency of   gulp [dev]                                                    

       Path            gulp > gulp-cli > matchdep > findup-sync > micromatch >       
                       extglob > expand-brackets > snapdragon > base > cache-base >  
                       union-value > set-value
```

Errors are repeated in the terminal with different paths.

Comment: Did you try npm audit fix?

Comment: It would help tremendously if you could share your package.json.

Comment: @Phix yes, of course.npm audit fix        
        npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 
       (node_modules\fsevents):
       npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
       fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
       {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
      up to date in 1.235s
      7 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details
      fixed 0 of 8 vulnerabilities in 374 scanned packages
      8 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated

Comment: @Trott https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tq-7bnVWBNUklGJwLCLO9XcS8-Cx8IbI/view?usp=sharing it's my package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `package.json` you posted in a comment, as of this writing at least, all your issues are in dev dependencies and none are in production dependencies. You can confirm this with `npm audit --omit=dev` which (as of this writing) shows 0 vulnerabilities.

At this point, a valid option is to decide not to worry about any of those issues reported by `npm`. You are, for example, extremely unlikely to trigger a denial of service issue via `glob-parent` (as reported in the snippet you provide) and in the vanishingly-small likelihood that you do, it will be a "denial of service" on your own tooling while running `gulp`. Literally, who cares?

But if you really want to get rid of these things: uninstall `gulp` and `check-dependencies`. The former hasn't published a new version in 2 years and you're not using it in your `package.json`. The latter hasn't published a new version in 4 years and isn't anything you can't live without. You aren't using either of those dev dependencies in your `package.json`. If you were planning on using `gulp`, consider using [`grunt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt) instead (currently, reports 0 vulnerabilities when installed) or [regular `npm` scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts).

TL;DR:

1. You can choose to ignore these. They are all in dev dependencies, at least as of this writing.
2. If ignoring them is not what you want to do, remove `gulp` and `check-dependencies`. You are not using them anyway, at least not yet.

If you are following along with a tutorial, definitely ignore the warnings for the purposes of the tutorial or find a more up-to-date tutorial.

Comment: Thank's for your very informative answer and your time.